# program that implements the `mkdir` command

Tags: c, file-system, homework

I wrote a program that creates a directory, similar to the `mkdir` command.
My question is, is this implementation correct? What else could I improve or what problems does implementation have?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "lab.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bool err = false;
    if(argc == 1)
    {
err_msg("missing operand\nTry 'mkdir --help' for more information.");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        if(access(argv[i],F_OK) == 0)
        {
            err_msg("cannot create directory ‘%s’: File exists",argv[i]);
            err = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(mkdir(argv[i], S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP | S_IXGRP | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH) == -1)
            {
                err_ret("cannot create directory '%s'",argv[i]);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    if(err == false)
        exit(0);
    else
        exit(1);
}
```

lab.h content:

````
/* Our own header, to be included *after* all standard system headers */

#ifndef __LAB_H__
#define __LAB_H__

#include    <sys/types.h>   /* required for some of our prototypes */
#include    <stdio.h>       /* for convenience */
#include    <stdlib.h>      /* for convenience */
#include    <string.h>      /* for convenience */
#include    <unistd.h>      /* for convenience */

#define MAXLINE 4096            /* max line length */

#define FILE_MODE   (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)
                    /* default file access permissions for new files */
#define DIR_MODE    (FILE_MODE | S_IXUSR | S_IXGRP | S_IXOTH)
                    /* default permissions for new directories */


                    /* prototypes for our own functions */
char    *path_alloc(int *);         /* {Prog pathalloc} */
int      open_max(void);            /* {Prog openmax} */
void     clr_fl(int, int);          /* {Prog setfl} */
void     set_fl(int, int);          /* {Prog setfl} */

void    err_dump(const char *, ...);    /* {App misc_source} */
void    err_msg(const char *, ...);
void    err_quit(const char *, ...);
void    err_ret(const char *, ...);
void    err_sys(const char *, ...);

#endif  /* __LAB_H__ */
```
````

Comment: And what about implementation of lab.h?

Comment: It's a header that must be in implementation

Comment: I know, so I was asking about coresponding c file.

Answer (score 4):

## Don't call `access()`

Calling `access()` before trying `mkdir()` results in a [TOCTTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). Some other process might create or delete the directory you are trying to `mkdir()` between the call to `access()` and `mkdir()`. Instead, just call `mkdir()` and check the value of `errno` to see if there was an error because the path already existed or if there was another reason:

```
if (mkdir(argv[1], ...) == -1) {
    err_ret("cannot create directory '%s'",argv[i]);

    if (errno == EEXIST) {
         err = true;
    } else {
         exit(1);
    }
}
```

## Don't exit immediately on error

The `mkdir` command will continue trying to make all specified directories, regardless of what kind of error occurs. So I would just set `err = true` in all cases, and not call `exit(1)` inside the `for`-loop.

## Consider using the BSD `err()` function

Instead of implementing your own `err_*()` functions, consider using [`err()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/err), `warn()` and related functions from BSD. These are supported on BSD, Linux and macOS. If you want to support Windows as well, I suggest implementing your own version of them and conditionally compile them only on Windows.